# Processes of Nodejs and Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

When starting nginx or nodejs, many processes are run. In addition to the processes that host ports 80 and 443 of nginx and port 8080 of nodejs. What do the roles of other processes do?

[image: Task Manager and netstat]